# My@Html.ValidationMessageFor keep showing error "The value 'null' is invalid"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, viewmodel

I want user not to select the empty string from option label so that's why I added `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DayOfWeek)` using the required annotation in vthe iew model:

```
@(Html.KendoEnumDropDownListFor(x => x.DayOfWeek , new { id = "DayOfWeekDropDown", @Name = "select-view", @Class = "select-view right" }, true,false).OptionLabel(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "DayOfWeekDropDown" }))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DayOfWeek)

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Day")]
        public DayOfWeek? DayOfWeek { get; set; }
```

How can I get rid of this message?

[image]

Comment: Do you excute the controller? When do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below code to make your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DayOfWeek)` work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

You can read [Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation) to know more.

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Yash Sawant , Is your problem solved ?